# data is not visible with mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a react application. And I am using mobx for central state management.

I have this two packages installed:

```
  "mobx": "^6.3.0",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.2.0",
```

and my files looks like this:

```
  export default class ActivityStore {
    
        constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);    
      }  

 loadActivities = async () => {
    this.loadingInitial = true;
    try {
      const activities = await agent.Activities.list();
      console.log(activities);
      activities.forEach((activity) => {
    
        activities.push(activity);
      });
      this.loadingInitial = false;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.loadingInitial = false;
     
    }
  };
    
    }
```

app.tsx:

```
useEffect(() => {

    activityStore.loadActivities();

    },
   [activityStore]);

   <ActivityDashboard
          activities={activityStore.activities}         
        />

export default observer(App);
```

So I see that data from the API call. in the console.

But I don't see the data in the web view.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `activityStore.activities` property in your store actually, you probably missed that part!

```js
export default class ActivityStore {
    // Add class property with some default value, array in this case
    activities = []
    // It is better to declare all properties beforehand, so delcare this one too
    loadingInitial = false

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    loadActivities = async () => {
        this.loadingInitial = true;
        try {
            const activities = await agent.Activities.list();

            // Assign fetched activities to class property right here
            this.activities = activities;

            this.loadingInitial = false;
        } catch (error) {
            this.loadingInitial = false;
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Whooo, thank you. But I still don't understand. Because I do a foreach().. and then I push each activity in the array list Activity. So why that doesn't  work??

Comment: You are just using local variable `const activities`. First you assign value of fetched items to it, then you do `forEach..push` to the same local variable. It never gets assigned to class property and will be lost after `loadActivities` invocation. If you did `this.activities.push(activity)` it would make more sense but still would not work because `this.activities` was never declared as array. Hope it make sense!

Comment: ah, thank you. Yes, I understand now. Thank you for your clear explanation